# Guide to integrating express checkout

Tags: express, paypal, checkout

Is there a guide on how to integrate the Paypal express checkout in an existing check out flow.

I have read the documentation, created the test accounts and so on. But I think I'm missing something.

The official documentation is awful and I've wasted a lot of time trying to figure out how to get this thing to work.

I'm afraid I have to implement the advanced version where I have to call back to the server.

I have implemented the page as follows:

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div> 

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

        client: {
            sandbox:    'Aa_Hj-VVA-wBzLnaZe5URjMmkR9_dJZLLtIhd5avXTmeJxclN2f90KBBHaFZnV0FcCnZ34lXT03neB09',
            production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        },

        payment: function() {

            var env    = this.props.env;
            var client = this.props.client;

            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            // Optional: display a confirmation page here

            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                // Show a success page to the buyer
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

which is basically taken directly from the documentation.

It shows a button and when I press it it shows the paypal entry popup. It shows the correct amount and so on.

How do I connect this script with my backend? When the Paypal checkout flow is done it doesn't seems to register anywhere. I don't see the transaction in my backend and no status code is shown to the user.

It just disappears.

I have looked at the demo paypal supplies but it seems to be implemented differently. And i don't understand why they don't show a very bare bone implementation in the documentation.

In the demo they use a merchant ID like this:

define("MERCHANT_ID","E9GCL5FX4TU2C");

when i look in my dashboard i can't find any value that resembles this. I have created an app and it has a Client ID like this:

Aa_Hj-VVA-wBzLnaZe5URjMmkR9_dJZLLtIhd5avXTmeJxclN2f......

But i can't find the merchant ID.

Any input welcome.
Kim

Comment: Which specific step are you having difficulty with? How far did you get?

Comment: I have created an account on  developer.paypal.com and created some test accounts. One business account and three customers. But I can't find my merchant ID for instance. I'm not sure if i have done the account creation correct.

Comment: Did you follow this page and click on "Create a PayPal app" to get the merchant id? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/

Comment: I have edited my answer. Thank you for spending your time to help me sort out this mess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your server in the `onAuthorize` callback:

```
   onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            // Make an ajax request to your server, or do a redirect
        });
    }
```